# Select from duplicated rows the biggest one

Tags: sql

I have a table with data like this

```
ID | second_col    
1  |    1
1  |    2
1  |    3
2  |    1
2  |    4
3  |    1
3  |    5
4  |    1
```

and i want select records from duplicated rows with the biggest number in second_col

the result should look as follows...

```
ID | second_col    
1  |    3
2  |    4
3  |    5
4  |    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server is being used, you could do the following:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(second_col)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I know, I was just covering my back in case some bizarre RDBMS is being used :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(second_col)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ID
```